# package created by install4j not recognised as newer

Tags: linux, rpm, install4j, apt

I have version "1.0" of my application installed on Linux (ubuntu and fedora). To test the update I created a version "1.1".
install4j downloads the package but then the package manager just tells me that this package is already installed.

This is so for both Ubuntu (apt) and Fedora (rpm).

"1.1" is greater than "1.0". But it seems linux is not looking at that. What is the best way to tell linux package managers that this is a newer version of the same package.
I also don't know if it would be possible to make a version "1.10" (major: 1 minor: 10) that would replace "1.9" and older.

I tried `rpm -i filename.rpm` and it tells me that it "collides" with the one already installed.
However, `sudo apt install ./filename.deb` actually installs version 1.1. Only the GUI program that ubuntu comes with only gives me the option to remove the package but not to upgrade.
Similarly it would also do a downgrade but in that case it prompts for a confirmation.

Comment: 1.1 is definitely newer than 1.0 and 1.10 is also newer than 1,9, both for install4j as well as for rpm and apt. See https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/versionNumbers.html for more details. What are the outputs of `rpm -qip <new package file>` and `rpm -qi <package name>`?

Comment: `$ rpm -qip filename.rpm` gives me `Version : 1.0` and `Version : 1.1` for the newer version. With version 1.0 installed and double-clicking on the newer package I get a window telling me that this is version "1.1-1" (version 1.1 + release 1) but the only option I get is "remove", not "update". It seems to be a problem with the gui installer only. But I had the same problem on ubuntu.